# Can't use xshift with decorations.markings in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I am using the library `decorations.markings` to mark the middle of a `plot` with a `\node`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{midmark/.style={
postaction=decorate,decoration={pre length=1pt, post length=1pt,
markings,mark=at position 0.5 with \node #1;}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[domain=0:pi,variable=\t,midmark={[above,xshift=1em]{text}}]
    plot (\t,{sin(deg(\t))});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But I get the error

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/\pgfkeyscurrent
name ', to which you passed '1em]{text};', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps
 you misspelled it.
```

There us no error if `,xshift=1em` is removed.

Also a `tikzpicture` containing `\node [above,xshift=1em]{text};` alone compiles without error.

Why can't we use `xshift` with `decorations.markings` and is there a workaround that doesn't involve redefining `midmark`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there's a problem with the way `midmark` takes in its argument. If you use curly braces to contain the node options, then everything works fine:

```
midmark={[{above,xshift=1em}]{text}}
```